# Is this correct $x\in\operatorname{supp}(f.g)\implies (f.g)(x)≠0\implies f(x)≠0 \operatorname{and} g(x)≠0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I'm going to understand those implications is correct or no

Let :

$f,g$ are two function then :

$$x\in\operatorname{supp}(f.g)\implies (f.g)(x)≠0\implies  f(x)≠0 \operatorname{and} g(x)≠0$$

For example take :

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,x\in[0,1]\\0,\operatorname{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1,x\in[2,3]\\0,\operatorname{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then :

$$\operatorname{supp}f=[0,1]$$

$$\operatorname{supp}g=[2,3]$$

So  not always : $f(x)≠0$ and $g(x)≠0$

I already to see your exploration !

Comment: If $f.g$ supposed to be the result of multiplying $f$ and $g$ pointwise? You can use `\cdot` for a single dot at mid-level: $f\cdot g$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\operatorname{supp}(h)$ is defined as the closure of $\{x\mid h(x) \neq 0\}$, the implication $x \in \operatorname{supp}(h) \implies h(x) \neq 0$ might be false on the boundary of $\operatorname{supp}(h)$.

Comment: thanks!, what about this $h(x)≠0\implies x\in \operatorname{supp}(h)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that should be true except when talking about [essential support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support).

Comment: You should note that there are [several definitions of support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) depending on the situation. In the set-theoretic definition your implications are true, but since you have tagged the question with 'real-analysis' I considered the "Closed support" definition to be the correct one in this case.